# Совмещение больше одного цвета текста в одной Cell, TreeTableView

Tags: java, javafx

Есть желание использовать больше одного цвета текста одновременно на одну клетку Cell в компоненте TreeTableView. Для примера - название папки дефолтным цветом, а путь к ней другим. Это осуществимо?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, возможно.

```
class CustomTableCell extends TableCell < MyType, File > {@
    Override
    protected void updateItem(File item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (item != null && !empty) {
            HBox box = new HBox();
            Label lblName = new Label(item.getName());
            lblName.setStyle("-fx-text-fill : gold");
            Label lblPath = new Label(item.getPath());
            lblPath.setStyle("-fx-text-fill : red");
            box.getChildren().addAll(lblPath, lblName);
            setGraphic(box);
        } else {
            setGraphic(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Применить можно так

```
TableColumn < MyType, File > column = new TableColumn < > ("File path column");
column.setCellFactory(param - > new CustomTableCell());
```

`MyType` - это то, чем у вас параметризирована `tableView`

Comment: Хм, гораздо легче, чем я мог представить

Answer (score 0):

Так как я немного отошел от принятого мной ответа, опубликую решение здесь же, может кому-то пригодится.

Для начала делаем fxml-разметку в виде `HBox`-контейнера с двумя `Label`-компонентами внутри. Настраиваем цвета и прочие характеристики по вкусу.
На внешний контейнер(`HBox` в данном случае) выставить `fx:root`.

*MultiColorTreeTableCell.fxml*

```
<fx:root maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" spacing="10.0" type="HBox" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="mNameLabel" />
      <Label fx:id="mPathLabel" opacity="0.75" textFill="#ababab">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Italic" size="15.0" />
         </font>
         <opaqueInsets>
            <Insets />
         </opaqueInsets>
      </Label>
   </children>
</fx:root>
```

Создаем контроллер нашего `Cell`-компонента. В конструкторе указываем Loader fxml-файла, передаем в качестве root-элемента тот объект, класс которого указан в `type`-параметре внешнего контейнера(которому мы выставили `fx:root`). В данном случае это объект `HBox`, но если класс от которого унаследован контроллер будет совпадать с классом внешнего контейнера из разметки fxml, то можно передать `this`.

В нашем случае это невозможно, так как наследование идет от `JFXTreeTableCell` (наследован от `TreeTableCell`, в свою очередь), а клетка не может быть контейнером в файле разметки.

Затем передаем контроллер(`this`).

*MultiColorTreeTableCell.java*

```
public class MultiColorTreeTableCell<S, T extends ObservableList<T>> extends JFXTreeTableCell<S, T> {
    @FXML
    private Label mNameLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label mPathLabel;


    public MultiColorTreeTableCell() {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(
                "MultiColorTreeTableCell.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(new HBox()); // Нужно передать экземпляр класса корневого элемента в разметке
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            setGraphic(fxmlLoader.load()); // Установка "многоцветной" графики для клетки
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T list, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(list, empty);

        if (list != null && !empty) {
            StringProperty nameProperty = (StringProperty)list.get(0);
            mNameLabel.setText(nameProperty.getValue());

            StringProperty pathProperty = (StringProperty)list.get(1);
            BooleanProperty isDirectoryProperty = (BooleanProperty)list.get(2);
            mPathLabel.setText((isDirectoryProperty.getValue()) ? "(" + pathProperty.getValue() + ")" : "");
        } else {
            setGraphic(null); // Сброс графики
        }
    }
}
```

И сама работа с этой клеткой в таблице.

*FiletreeController.java*

```
    public class FiletreeController {
    @FXML
    private GridPane mCenterGridPane;
    @FXML
    private BorderPane mMainPane;
    @FXML
    private JFXTreeTableView<FileTreeObject> mTreeTableView;
    private JFXTreeTableColumn<FileTreeObject, ObservableList<Object>> mFileFullNameCol;
    @FXML
    private VBox mInfoVBox;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        mFileFullNameCol = new JFXTreeTableColumn<>("Имя файла");
        mFileFullNameCol.setCellFactory(param -> new MultiColorTreeTableCell()); // Устанавливаем наш многоцветный объект Cell
        mFileFullNameCol.setCellValueFactory(param ->
                new SimpleListProperty<>(
                        FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                                param.getValue().getValue().fileFullName(),
                                param.getValue().getValue().filePath(),
                                param.getValue().getValue().isDirectory()
                        )
                )
        ); // Передаем список данных для отображения в Cell
        mFileFullNameCol.setStyle( "-fx-alignment: TOP-LEFT;");

        mTreeTableView.getColumns().setAll(mFileFullNameCol);
        mTreeTableView.setRoot(getTreeItem(new File("D:\\Downloads")));
    }

    private TreeItem<FileTreeObject> getTreeItem(File currentFile){
        TreeItem<FileTreeObject> item = new TreeItem<FileTreeObject>(new FileTreeObject(currentFile.getPath(), currentFile.isDirectory()));

        if (currentFile.isDirectory()) {
            item.setExpanded(true);
            File[] files = currentFile.listFiles();
            if (files != null)
                for (File file : files)
                    try {
                        item.getChildren().add(getTreeItem(file));
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
                        //e.printStackTrace();
                    }
        }

        return item;
    }
}

class FileTreeObject extends RecursiveTreeObject<FileTreeObject> {...} // Объект данных TreeItem
```